# Multiple logarithmic integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How would one go to prove that

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{d}(x, y,z)}{ \ln x + \ln y + \ln z} = - \frac{1}{2}$$

I'm not good handling multivariable integrals and nothing pops up in my head.

**Note:** It should be noted that for two variables or one variable the integral diverges.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by the denominator, which equals $\ln(xyz)$, we change variables,
$$
u=xyz,\quad v=y,\quad w=z.
$$
Then you will have the integral
$$
\iiint_K\frac{1}{vw\ln u}\,du\,dv\,dw.
$$
Here, $K$ is determined by the inequalities
$$
\frac{u}{w}\leq v\leq 1,\quad u\leq w\leq 1,\quad 0\leq u\leq 1.
$$
If you integrate in that given order (first $v$, then $w$ and last $u$), you will soon find that the integral equals $-1/2$. I leave those calculations to you.

Comment: Thank you... the calculations you left are so easy...

Answer (score 3):

Interview question finalized in one line

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx dydz }{ \log(x y z)}=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}\int_1^{\infty}-(xyz)^{s-1}dsdx dydz=\int_1^{\infty}-\frac{1}{s^3}ds=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: @Tolaso, Is my answer perfect or you're again too confused about it to upvote?

Comment: It's amazing how you grouped $x,y,z$ in one variable, you'r a magician.